# Cannot shutdown JBoss AS 7.0.2 from windows command line

Tags: windows, jboss, gradle, jboss7.x

Hi all I'm new on JBoss and I'm learning how to write a gradle script to automate deployment process on JBoss. I've read a lot of articles and they are all saying the command is:

```
{JBOSS_HOME}/bin/jboss-admin.bat --connect command=:shutdown
```

But it always says the controller is not available, I'm sure the server is already started:

```
C:\jboss-as-web-7.0.2.Final\bin>jboss-admin.bat --connect command=:shutdown
Authenticating against security realm: 127.0.0.1
The controller is not available at localhost:9999
You are disconnected at the moment. Type 'connect' to connect to the server or '
help' for the list of supported commands.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I know that I changed the property file after installation and now the admin CLI requires credential, but I could not find a way to pass username and password along with the admin.bat, so in what way could I shut it down? Thanks

Comment: Is that link helpful for You: http://middlewaremagic.com/jboss/?p=419 ?

Comment: @Opal Thanks it is very comprehensive, but it still didn't tell me how to pass username and password into admin.bat from windows command line.

Comment: Have You read the script? If You pass `--connect` maybe other options are defined as well. Have You tried `--username` and `--password`? No idea then, just a guess.

Comment: @Opal I already tried, but no luck. I found a [ticket](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-2036) from JBoss community, do you think they are saying it is impossible to do that on 7.0.2?

Answer (score 0):

According to the official documentation, they did not provide that functionality in 7.0.2, but they already added that option in the later versions.